# Count Unqiue Value from a cell in excel

Tags: excel

I have a value in cell A2 as `India,China,India Australia`. I want the result at Cell B2 as `India,China,Australia`.

Note I want a formula to find the unique value from a single cell not in the range of cell. Since so much were replied with `countif` can do the unqiue count. I don't want such thing I want the formula to calculate to find  unique value from a single cell only.
Please have a look at my question clearly and suggest an answer.

Comment: India is not a Unique value. The list you are creating are distinct values. A redhead in a sea of blonds is unique, there are two distinct hair colors.

Comment: Let it be no issue, if not unique then give me a solution for to calculate distinct count and distinct names as per the requirement.

Comment: with vba? Without vba or helper columns, very convoluted.

Comment: I meant no disrespect, I just wanted you to have the correct terms when researching solutions.

Comment: Ok I understood, i want the result through formula is my ideal preference but if it cannot be done through it then suggest me in other ways. I am being searched answer for this more than 4 months hence please suggest a solution

Comment: I have more than 35k rows like this, and it has value like 52 words maximum in a single cell, i could not put all those in this that's why i mentioned simply like an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### VBA Distinct UDF

This is a user defined formula for finding the distinct words in a string of words.

- The only word delimiters are commas and/or spaces.

Place in a standard VBA Module

- Not a class module and not a sheet module.
- Either add to an existing module or create a new module.

Use the function the same way other cell formula functions are used.

- **`=Distinct("a,a,b,c, d e f f f")`**

  - output `a, b, c, d, e, f`
- A1=`Apples, App Pear Apples Pear Bees,` B1`=Distinct(A1)`

  - output `Apples, App, Pear, Bees`

VBA code

```
Public Function Distinct(ByVal s As String) As String
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim f As Variant
    Dim w As Variant
    Dim a() As String
    a = Split("") 'empty array
    For Each w In Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(Replace(s, ",", " ")), " ")
        found = False
        For Each f In a
            If f = w Then found = True
        Next f
        If Not found Then
            ReDim Preserve a(UBound(a) + 1)
            a(UBound(a)) = w
        End If
    Next w
    Distinct = Join(a, ", ") ' Change to "," to remove space in output.
End Function
```

The Distinct word count can be found with this formula:
`=IF( Distinct(A1)="", 0, LEN( Distinct(A1)) - LEN( SUBSTITUTE( Distinct(A1), ",", "")) + 1)`
Counts commas (and ignores spaces) so it still works even if the VBA code is modified to output `a,b,c`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But any other way to do through formula since i am unable to understand the concept of this. I have searched in web there are formula called distinct and distinctcount which can be used only if i convert my data into data model but once i do that my file size has become very big.

Comment: However thank a ton for your suggest it works perfectly at my workbook. Also i need a formula to calculate days between two dates. Below is the sample data

Comment: It works perfectly at my workbook. Also i need a formula to calculate days between two dates. Departure date 02/06/2018, arrival date 03/06/2018 hence my answer would be 2 days which includes departure date like wise if any dates are getting repeated in subsequent cells that should not get counted, days calculation should be done for only distinct dates. For an example i have already count days for date 02 & 03/06/2018, so for those dates no count calculation to be done after this. This is a sample data of one employee  like wise i have 3000 employees.

Comment: I am glad it helped. Please give the answer an upvote and mark it as the accepted solution as applicable. Also, regarding the date problem in your comment, as it is not a refinement to this question, please submit a new post for the problem. I will need to see the whole description and the comments are not the right place to spell it all out and adequately describe a completely different question.